# .htaccess file in XAMPP is not working on windows 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

I have the following URL on my localhost:

```
http://localhost/?cmd=causeListByCourtName 
http://localhost/?cmd=here could be any other page name
```

I have tried to rewrite the URL like =

```
http://localhost/page/causeListByCourtName
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)/?$   .+/?cmd=$1   [NC,L]    
# Handle pages requests
```

But it do nothing. I am using XAMPP on my windows 7.
in my httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is already enabled. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change **pages** to **page** in `RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)/?$   .+/?cmd=$1   [NC,L]`?

Comment: As always when trying to debug rewriting: ENABLE REWRITE LOGGING! Otherwise you are trying to _guess_ why things don't work, that is a joke. Take a look into the excellent documentation, enable logging and see how things work.

Comment: dear Seçkin its still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also make sure you changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in your httpd.conf file wherever you find it.

Try doing it this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)/?$ /?cmd=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: if i need to work with two parameters or more i.e. '?cmd=pageName&id=34' what should i need to add with?

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

This in case you use index.php as your default page. You can cut down the index.php from the front